# Is there a special name for keyboards that only have a few keys?

Tags: keyboard, terminology

#### Background

I am building a custom embedded computer system and need only a few keys to be accessible by the users. I could attach a button board and program that in but was thinking it would be easier to just use and/or mod a 5 key keyboard. I have seen them before but cannot seem to find them online; it could be 6 keys as well preferably in a row.

#### Research

The closest thing I've found is [chorded keyboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorded_keyboard) which are similar to what I'm looking for but rather expensive.

#### Question

Does anyone know what you call a keyboard that has only a few keys on it?

#### Updates

In response to the comments here are some clarifications:

- My project is a portable bluethooth and FM radio speaker.
- The embeded system is the [Raspberry Pi Zero](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/pi-zero/) using the [Zero4U](https://www.adafruit.com/products/3298) to add USB ports.
- Bluetooth is added with a tiny USB dongle as well as the FM receiver.
- I need 6 keys preferably, 5 could work, in a row is the best.
- Something like the [Cooler Master DIY Micro Keyboard](https://youtu.be/GGB6EvkvXwc) is what I think I'll do.
- Googling **Micro Keyboard** or **Macro Programmable Keyboard** gives the best results.

I have found some awesome resources and ideas because of your answers. I will add these when I have time in an answer to help everyone else. I will also leave this question open for a bit to encourage more answers. This has become a great resource so please keep adding.

Comment: I think it's easier to ask here http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I did my homework before posting. This is the stack exchange best suited for this question. I will remove hobbyist. I think that might confuse people.

Comment: I don't know if it has a proper name, but googling "4-keys keypad" or some number-keys keypad seems to come up with some result. If you check sites that sells primarily electronics equipment like element14 - they have heaps of different options, but all of them usually have some component cabling out (not your standard USB) - so I'm not sure if that is what you're after.

Comment: What's your hardware platform?  Have you got GPIOs to spare? [example for Raspberry Pi](https://www.adafruit.com/products/419) that would work on other things

Comment: Googling for *Cheap 6 key keyboard* leads here: http://www.dx.com/p/6-key-usb-handle-hid-keyboard-173cm-cable-70892, which shows a 6 key 'usb handle' (?) keyboard for ₤ 8.43 and a numeric keypad for ₤ 4.65. There is also this $45 keyboard: http://techkeys.us/products/sixkeyboard

Comment: may be you can use something like this? http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-18-Keys-Mini-Keyboard-Wireless-USB-Number-Pad-Laptop-Numeric-Keypad-I1Z8/162111404010?_trksid=p2047675.c100623.m-1&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D38530%26meid%3D1237df04daa4451d83afb77abdfc2a65%26pid%3D100623%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D201480333018

Comment: or this one? http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-Slim-USB-Wired-Numeric-Keypad-Number-Pad-Keyboard-18-Keys-Ergonomic-Z2I4/291834846141?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D38530%26meid%3D6f4b3f4c6bad4d48b4031f2b84aa4715%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D162111404010? It's wired and even cheaper

Comment: Six keys? [6-Key Cherry MX Switch Tester](https://www.amazon.com/WASD-6-Key-Cherry-Switch-Tester/dp/B00AZQKCD4). If you wanted them to all have the same feel then you could replace five of the keys. ISTR seeing a version which is actually wired up too.

Comment: @AndrewMorton that is exactly the route I was thinking of going! I found that last night as well.

Comment: @Blizzardengle If you're going to be making a few, you can get square hole punches for metal. Or a local sheet metal shop could run you off a few.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_keyboard :

> A keyboard with few keys is called a keypad.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keypad:

> A keypad is a set of buttons arranged in a block or "pad" which usually bear digits, symbols and usually a complete set of alphabetical letters. If it mostly contains numbers then it can also be called a numeric keypad.

If you have a few more keys, you could call it a [40%](http://www.mechtype.com/mechanical-keyboard-terminology/):

> 40% – Extremely small form factor with only the bare minimal of dedicated keys required to function. No alphanumeric keys, F-row or numpad. Many standard key operations will be hidden under multiple function layers. Some keys will be of a non-standard size.

Or alternatively, you could call it [Apple Keyboard 2018](http://mashable.com/2016/10/27/twitter-reactions-apple-removes-escape-key/#sMJQLuQPliqW).

---

[Example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AC73IZ4):

[image]

Comment: Ya I read that already and if you search those "Key pad" or "Key block" nothing like I'm referring to in my question comes up. I already found that example for $90. That is insane!

Comment: Small-run electronics in nice injection-moulded cases does tend to be much more expensive than mass-produced stuff. Another term is "bump bar" http://bematechus.com/products/kitchen-systems/bump-bar/kb1700/

Answer (score 6):

Why not simply get the standard 9-10 digit [Numeric Keypad](http://www.officeworks.com.au/shop/officeworks/p/targus-numeric-keypad-black-and-grey-taakp10us), cover up some of the buttons you don't use, and overlay a paper on top with actual buttons / instructions you do use? (Example as below):

[image: Standard USB Numeric Keypad with Custom Keycaps]

This is the same method POS (Point of Sale) systems often used. They used a default keyboard, but pre-programmed each key for specific functions (or for adding pre-programmed items) and they overlayed the keyboard with a piece of paper (or maybe plastic-covered paper to make it somewhat water-resistant) with the correct program / function of the buttons.

If you want it to look better you can get your own custom-colored-printed-keycaps:

[image]

The reason what you wanted is expensive is because it is custom-built for a certain purpose. Anything that is not mass-produced is always more expensive.

Comment: My build is barely bigger than a bar of soap. I'll update my question to point that out. Also I just can't find them again but it was a gamer thing. A 5 key mini keyboard for $10

Comment: An 8 keys pad? - http://www.maxkeyboard.com/max-falcon-8-custom-programmable-mini-macropad-mechanical-keyboard-assembled.html but yeah not cheap... (not $10)

Comment: I like that 8 key pad. Expensive but in the right direction and I'm sure with digging I can just buy the board and finish it myself.

Comment: Gamers wants things that can handle a rough time.  This does not sound like a $10 device.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Cherry key gamer keyboards are around $1.25 per key - the keys being most of the cost - so $10 for 8 keys isn't necessarily low quality.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Well, can you get Cherry key gamer keyboard in 8 key variants?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Theres plenty of small run electronics manufacturers who would put a pcb ($0.50) in a nice metal box ($2.50) with eight Cherry MX keys ($5) and a USB HID microcontroller ($1), and if you order 1000 it could easily be below that price assembled. Whether there's enough of a market that someone is already doing that I do not know. The one in the link could probably be made and sold at a profit for $10 - it's only a sheet metal case so that's less than the cost above, so they either have a massive profit margin or excessive labour cost doing each one as a one-off.

Comment: @PeteKirkham But does OP need 1000 or more?  I don't think that your numbers hold.

Answer (score 0):

- You could try with the terms "mini game controller"
- there are all sort of form factors, maybe one fits your needs,
- and they should be available in the "cheap price range" < 10 USD.

Examples:

- [https://www.amazon.com/Genius-Pandora-Pro-mini-retractable/dp/B000OE07AA/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000OE07AA)